# Hdfs file path in HA cluster

Tags: hadoop

I have migrated to a HA Hadoop cluster recently. Previously I used to add a cache file using the path:

```
hdfs://[host]:8020/data/locations.csv
```

How do I specify the path in HA cluster? If I use the following path, I get `FileNotFoundException`:

```
hdfs://[dfs.nameservices]/data/locations.csv
```

Comment: what gives you filenotfound exception?

Comment: When I use 
job.addCacheFile(new URI("hdfs://[dfs.nameservices]/data/locations.csv
"));
in my MapReduce code, I get the exception.

Comment: why don't you use `"/data/locations.csv"` without any prefix? or you need to use real HA name, like `"hfds://hanamenode/locations.csv"`

Comment: I tried both, and got the same exception.